# Selecting chained records from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to make a recursive SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53108/is-it-possible-to-make-a-recursive-sql-query)

Imagine an application where one would want to keep a history of the changes made to a 'record' in a database.

This can be realized by introducing a column 'revised_id' which points to the newer version of the record.

```
id  value                               revised_id
--------------------------------------------------
1   Initial value...                    3
2   Value of a different record         Null
3   Value which has been altered        4
4   Value which has been altered again  Null
```

The table illustrates two 'actual records', one of which has been altered two times

Getting all the latest versions simply means adding revised_id = null to the WHERE clause. To get the previous version simply: SELECT * FROM table WHERE revised_id = $current_id

My questing is: would it be possible to select all te previous versions of a given record?(The problem being that simple comparisons do not suffice because the records to be selected are 'chained' together.)

Comment: What you're looking for is a [recursive query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980611/postgres-recursive-query-on-the-same-table)

Comment: Interesting how not knowing what it's called can keep you from finding the answer... Anyway, **thanks guys!**

Comment: This table looks like it lacks a per-record fixed identifier (independent of the revision). Without that how to identify a "given record" in the first place? And once you have that you probably no longer need the recursive query.

Comment: @DanielVérité: That hadn't even occurred to me...

Comment: You may have a good reason for doing it this way but I have always found it more useful to have one table containing only the current value and a seperate table that contains all changes with additional timestamps and information who made the change where from.

Comment: It's often *much* easier to work with either (a) an separate audit table that logs changes; or (b) "created time" and "deleted time" fields that let you do temporal queries. The approach you suggest will work but is likely to have truly awful performance.